# How to trace or to check history of redirected URLs with python only urllib library

Tags: python, redirect, urllib

When you go to https://httpbin.org/redirect/6 after 6 redirection, you will lead to `https://httpbin.org/get`. I want to check what URLs are in between - only using python urllib.request.

```
import urllib.request

def openurl(url):

    headers = {}

    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
    httpResponse = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    code = httpResponse.getcode()

    httpHeader = httpResponse.info()
    httpBody = httpResponse.read().decode()

    return httpHeader, httpBody, code

url = 'https://httpbin.org/redirect/6'
h, b, c = openurl(url)
print(h)
print(b)
print('http Response Code:', c)
```

Is there any way to tweak the behavior of urlopen inorder to produce a list of URLs in between?

P.S. I cannot vote your answer as my reputation is below 15 otherwise unless I obtain 4 more points.

Comment: Is it really important to only use `urllib`? The `requests` package does this (and many other things) very easily.

Comment: It is important to use a standard library such as socket or urllib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with georgexsh,
But you can also modify the `HTTPRedirectHandler` as below which is shorter:

```
class MyHTTPRedirectHandler(urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

it is a simple task by building your own `HTTPRedirectHandler`:

```
import urllib.request

class MyHTTPRedirectHandler(urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        print("newurl", headers["location"])
        return super().http_error_302(req, fp, code, msg, headers)

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(MyHTTPRedirectHandler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://httpbin.org/redirect/6')
response.read()
```